# Python 3 one-liner for 2 lists string format?

Tags: python, list, string-formatting, list-comprehension

I have 2 lists in a python3 Class:

```
self.keys = ["a","b","c","d"]
self.values = [1,2,3,4]
```

len(self.keys) == len(self.values), always.

I want to create a string that mimic the printing output of a dictionary: `{a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4}`

I do it in a method that contains:

```
sr = ""
for i,k in enumerate(self.keys):
    sr += "{}:{},".format(k,self.values[i])
return "{%s}" % sr[:len(sr)-1]
```

Is it possible in one line ? if not, is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and then make it a [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict):

```
keys = ["a","b","c","d"]
values = [1,2,3,4]

dict(zip(keys, values))
```

Output:

```
{'b': 2, 'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```

Comment: Thx, I didn't even think about using dict() ...:$

Comment: @erebos007 :) Don't worry about it. Now you know! :)

Comment: @erebos007 If this works for you, you might want to store the data in a dictionary in the first place, rather than splitting up keys and values into separate lists.

Comment: @Sven Marnach It is an exercise where I have to create a Class that has the behavior of a dict() using 2 lists. Here it was for the __repr__() method, purely academic :)

Answer (score 4):

Why not just print a dictionary? Use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip) to make tuples of the pairs, then pass them to the [dict constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict).

```
print(dict(zip(self.keys, self.values)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the exactly the format your original code produces with a single line of code, you could use

```
from itertools import starmap

print("{%s}" % ",".join(starmap("{}:{}".format, zip(keys, values))))
```

I'm not sure this is more readable than your original code though.